# PHP: Random numbers, no duplicate, no previous and following number

Tags: php, random, numbers

The code below produces 3 random no repeating numbers out of 15.

```
function num($min, $max, $count){
    $count = abs((int)$count);
    if($min > $max){
        list($min, $max) = array($max, $min);
    }
    $u = abs($max - $min);
    if($count > $u)$count = $u;
    $numresult = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numresult);
    return array_slice($numresult, 0, $count);
}
foreach(num(1, 15, 3) as $rnum){
    echo $rnum, ' ';
}
```

Is there a way to also exclude the previous and the next number when a random pick occurs? For example: If the first picked number is 7, then 6, 7 and 8 should be excluded for the next two picks. Currently, only 7 is excluded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going to have to apply a bit more cleverness:

```
function getNumbers($min=1,$max=10,$count=1,$margin=0) {
    $range = range(0,$max-$min);
    $return = array();
    for( $i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        if( !$range) {
            trigger_error("Not enough numbers to pick from!",E_USER_WARNING);
            return $return;
        }
        $next = rand(0,count($range)-1);
        $return[] = $range[$next]+$min;
        array_splice($range,max(0,$next-$margin),$margin*2+1);
    }
    return $return;
}
```

To call:

```
echo implode(", ",getNumbers(1,15,3,1));
```

Comment: Alright this is awesome! And it works out of the box. Thank you very much!

Comment: As a general rule, to ensure it works, you should have your arguments such that `$max-$min > ($margin*2+1)*$count`. This will ensure that, regardless of what the result is, it will be able to actually give you a result every time. In this particular case, `14 > 9` so you're fine.